# Join wip_discrete_jobs_v and wip_move_transactions_v

Tags: sql, oracle, view, inline

I am trying to select * from wip_discrete_jobs_v, but also select just the latest move row from wip_move_transactions_v for a particular wip_entity_id and organization_id.  My result would only be one row per wip_entity_id, with only the most latest(most recent) row from the wip_move_transactions_v view.

I can't seem to figure out how to join, or use inline view, to get only the latest(most recent) move from the move view.

Could someone please help with the SQL.  Seems easy, but I am having a mental block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the columns in your views you should be able to use `row_number()` to return one row for each `wip_entity_id`:

```
select *
from
(
    select * -- replace this with the columns that you want
       , row_number() over(partition by j.wip_entity_id order by m.trans_date desc) rn
    from wip_discrete_jobs_v j
    inner join wip_move_transactions_v m
        on j.wip_entity_id = m.wip_entity_id  -- add the columns you join on 
        and j.organization_id = m.organization_id
) d
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks bluefeet.  Your answer was correct and it was faster than the solution I had come up with.

--bluefeet's way, 2 seconds

```
select *
from
(select 
     j.wip_entity_id
    ,m.transaction_date
    ,m.to_operation_seq_num
    ,row_number() over(partition by j.wip_entity_id order by m.transaction_date desc) rn
    from wip_discrete_jobs_v j
    inner join wip_move_transactions_v m
        on j.wip_entity_id = m.wip_entity_id 
        and j.organization_id = m.organization_id
        and j.status_type in (3,6)
) d
where 1=1
  and rn = 1
  and to_operation_seq_num = 30
order by d.wip_entity_id desc;
```

--my way, 53 seconds

```
select
 j.wip_entity_id
,m.transaction_date
,m.to_operation_seq_num
from wip_discrete_jobs_v j, wip_move_transactions_v m
where 1=1
  and j.status_type in (3,6)
  and m.wip_entity_id = j.wip_entity_id
  and m.to_operation_seq_num = 30
  and m.organization_id = j.organization_id
  and m.transaction_id = (select max(transaction_id) from WIP_MOVE_TRANSACTIONS_v where wip_entity_id = j.wip_entity_id)
order by j.wip_entity_id desc;
```